# mail -r option being ignored

Tags: centos, mailx

I am running this command on 2 different CentOS machines.  One changes the "from" like I would expect, the other does not.  What would I need to look at to determine what is messed up in my settings to fix this problem?

Command:

```
mail -s "test email" -r fromemail@fake.com -- toemail@fake.com << EOF
test email
EOF
```

And the machine that works:

```
> lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
Release:        6.7
Codename:       Final

> sudo yum info postfix
Loaded plugins: changelog, fastestmirror, presto
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.web-ster.com
 * epel: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * extras: mirror.web-ster.com
 * updates: mirror.web-ster.com
Installed Packages
Name        : postfix
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 2
Version     : 2.6.6
Release     : 6.el6_7.1
Size        : 9.7 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : updates
Summary     : Postfix Mail Transport Agent
URL         : http://www.postfix.org
License     : IBM
Description : Postfix is a Mail Transport Agent (MTA), supporting LDAP, SMTP AUTH (SASL),
            : TLS

Available Packages
Name        : postfix
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 2
Version     : 2.6.6
Release     : 8.el6
Size        : 2.0 M
Repo        : base
Summary     : Postfix Mail Transport Agent
URL         : http://www.postfix.org
License     : IBM
Description : Postfix is a Mail Transport Agent (MTA), supporting LDAP, SMTP AUTH (SASL),
            : TLS
```

The machine that does not work:

```
> lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-ia32:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
Release:        6.9
Codename:       Final
> sudo yum info postfix
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repo1.ash.innoscale.net
 * epel: mirror.math.princeton.edu
 * epel-debuginfo: mirror.math.princeton.edu
 * extras: mirror.atlantic.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.math.princeton.edu
 * rpmfusion-free-updates-debuginfo: mirror.math.princeton.edu
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: mirror.math.princeton.edu
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-debuginfo: mirror.math.princeton.edu
 * updates: ewr.edge.kernel.org
Installed Packages
Name        : postfix
Arch        : i686
Epoch       : 2
Version     : 2.6.6
Release     : 8.el6
Size        : 9.4 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : base
Summary     : Postfix Mail Transport Agent
URL         : http://www.postfix.org
License     : IBM
Description : Postfix is a Mail Transport Agent (MTA), supporting LDAP, SMTP AUTH (SASL),
            : TLS
```

Now obviously there are some version differences, but why would a newer version of the OS or postfix impact this?  Also, in this case, the mailx command ( "mail" is an alias to "mailx" ) are both the same version.  I am thinking it is some strange configuration issue, just don't know where to look.

Obviously, I cannot take the chance of breaking the machine that works, so I cannot update it so all the versions match.

UPDATE:
I did the following test, still same problem ( from email not correct, and "reply to" does not work ):

```
echo "Temp test" | mail -s "Test email" -r "fromemail@fromemail.com" -- toemail@toemail.com

sudo grep "Mar 22 13:26" /var/log/maillog
Mar 22 13:26:22 wmsCentOSdev1 postfix/pickup[11260]: 2E00A2844E3: uid=1031 from=<fromemail@fromemail.com>
Mar 22 13:26:22 wmsCentOSdev1 postfix/cleanup[11995]: 2E00A2844E3: message-id=<5c951abd.TB7ek4rlLmuYRH9a%fromemail@fromemail.com>
Mar 22 13:26:22 wmsCentOSdev1 postfix/qmgr[2967]: 2E00A2844E3: from=<fromemail@fromemail.com>, size=467, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 22 13:26:24 wmsCentOSdev1 postfix/smtp[11997]: 2E00A2844E3: to=<toemail@toemail.com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[2607:f8b0:4002:c00::6d]:587, delay=2.9, delays=0.26/0.27/0.58/1.7, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1553275584 205sm3453486ywd.15 - gsmtp)
Mar 22 13:26:24 wmsCentOSdev1 postfix/qmgr[2967]: 2E00A2844E3: removed
```

Not sure if this is important, but did the same test on the machine that works and here is the maillog, showing a difference in the "relay" value.  Could that be the problem?

```
Mar 22 13:41:23 app postfix/pickup[16506]: CBC0469435: uid=1014 from=<fromemail@fromemail.com>
Mar 22 13:41:23 app postfix/cleanup[19431]: CBC0469435: message-id=<5c951e43.usMAOJ1nzo2Bewl5%fromemail@fromemail.com>
Mar 22 13:41:23 app postfix/qmgr[1108]: CBC0469435: from=<fromemail@fromemail.com>, size=458, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 22 13:42:04 app postfix/smtp[19433]: CBC0469435: to=<toemail@toemail.com>, relay=mail.mobiwms.com[23.229.187.200]:25, delay=41, delays=0.04/0.01/20/21, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK id=1h7OBA-00CWCd-8G)
Mar 22 13:42:04 app postfix/qmgr[1108]: CBC0469435: removed
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was my postfix setup.  See below for the changes I made ( main.cf is the current version, of course ):

```
diff main.cf.20190322 main.cf
119c119
< inet_protocols = all
---
> inet_protocols = ipv4
704,710c704,710
< relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
< smtp_use_tls = yes
< smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
< smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
< smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
< smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
< smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
---
> ##relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
> ##smtp_use_tls = yes
> ##smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
> ##smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
> ##smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
> ##smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
> ##smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
```

It is not perfect ( I see a bounce error from google in maillog, but the email still goes through ), but definitely better.  Maybe this will help someone else.